# C++: C2511: Overloaded member function not found. problems when using 'this'

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have this one object that tries to call a function in another class's function. That function looks like this (Belongs to class 'Player' ):

```
void play(Game *const currentGame, int x, int y);
```

When I try to call this function from another object (of the Game class) like this :

```
player->play(this, x, y)
```

And during compilation I get these errors:

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Game'   c:\users\shaqed\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\exe3\tictactoe.h  24  1   Exe3
Error   3   error C2511: 'void Player::play(Game *const ,int,int)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Player'   c:\users\shaqed\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\exe3\tictactoe.cpp    40  1   Exe3
Error   4   error C2660: 'Player::play' : function does not take 3 arguments    c:\users\shaqed\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\exe3\tictactoe.cpp    158 1   Exe3
```

I came from Java, so maybe I lack some of the core principles about pointers and reference, however I could figure out why there's a type mismatch in here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Always fix the first error first. It looks like the others are cascading errors of that. When it reaches the declaration of the `play` method in the header, apparently it doesn't know what `Game` is. Is it declared or pre-declared before that point?

Answer (score 0):

I have repeated your problem with the same compile errors. I think you have forgotten to add at the end of your method the body. Like:

void play(const Game *currentGame, int x, int y){}

Comment: `Game *const currentGame` is perfectly valid (albeit probably not what was intended). It declares a parameter named `currentGame` that is `const` (cannot be re-assigned to within the method body) and points to a `Game` object.